# Python 3.5 - Placing Buttons on Top of Buttons

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

So I am creating a piano program that plays sound when a button is pressed on the tkinter gui interface. When I place the buttons at the places I want them to be. The black keys for the piano are behind the white keys. [Image Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MjoHd.png).

How can I make it so that the black keys are on top of the white keys.

Code Below

```
from tkinter import *
import winsound
Gui=Tk()
Gui.title("Piano")
Gui.geometry("400x400")

def PianoF():
    winsound.PlaySound("PianoF.wav",winsound.SND_ASYNC)
def PianoGb():
    winsound.PlaySound("PianoGb.wav",winsound.SND_ASYNC)
def PianoG():
    winsound.PlaySound("PianoG.wav",winsound.SND_ASYNC)
def PianoAb():
    winsound.PlaySound("PianoAb.wav",winsound.SND_ASYNC)
def PianoA():
    winsound.PlaySound("PianoA.wav",winsound.SND_ASYNC)
def PianoBb():
    winsound.PlaySound("PianoBb.wav",winsound.SND_ASYNC)
def PianoB():
    winsound.PlaySound("PianoB.wav",winsound.SND_ASYNC)
def PianoC():
    winsound.PlaySound("PianoC.wav",winsound.SND_ASYNC)
def PianoDb():
    winsound.PlaySound("PianoDb.wav",winsound.SND_ASYNC)
def PianoD():
    winsound.PlaySound("PianoD.wav",winsound.SND_ASYNC)
def PianoEb():
    winsound.PlaySound("PianoEb.wav",winsound.SND_ASYNC)
def PianoE():
    winsound.PlaySound("PianoE.wav",winsound.SND_ASYNC)

FNote=Button(Gui,height=15,width=6,bg='white',command=PianoF)
GbNote=Button(Gui,height=9,width=5,bg='black',command=PianoGb)
GNote=Button(Gui,height=15,width=6,bg='white',command=PianoG)
AbNote=Button(Gui,height=9,width=5,bg='black',command=PianoAb)
ANote=Button(Gui,height=15,width=6,bg='white',command=PianoA)
BbNote=Button(Gui,height=9,width=5,bg='black',command=PianoBb)
BNote=Button(Gui,height=15,width=6,bg='white',command=PianoB)
CNote=Button(Gui,height=15,width=6,bg='white',command=PianoC)
DbNote=Button(Gui,height=9,width=5,bg='black',command=PianoDb)
DNote=Button(Gui,height=15,width=6,bg='white',command=PianoD)
EbNote=Button(Gui,height=9,width=5,bg='black',command=PianoEb)
ENote=Button(Gui,height=15,width=6,bg='white',command=PianoE)


GbNote.place(x=28,y=0)
AbNote.place(x=84,y=0)
BbNote.place(x=140,y=0)
DbNote.place(x=252,y=0)
EbNote.place(x=308,y=0)

FNote.place(x=0,y=0)
GNote.place(x=56,y=0)
ANote.place(x=112,y=0)
BNote.place(x=168,y=0)
CNote.place(x=224,y=0)
DNote.place(x=280,y=0)
ENote.place(x=336,y=0)
```

Comment: In the image the black keys are on top of the white keys so what's the point?

Comment: The black keys are not fully on top of it, the right side of the black keys are clipped behind the white key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for w in (ANote, BNote, CNote, DNote, ENote, FNote, GNote):
    w.lower()
```

Using a list instead of that type of names would be better.

Comment: Thank you very much, this has solved my problem. Now it looks like a proper piano